# JSON read a local file using JavaScript (similar questions Stack overflow didnt help)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to read a local .JSON file and use JSON.parse to put it into a Javascript array. Any other piece of example code would also help. I am unable to do it using the following code, its not able to load a local file.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("application/json"); //this line also didnt help
var url = "sample.json";
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        testme(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.send(); 

function testme(response){

    var record = JSON.parse(response);
    var out = "<table>";

    for(var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) { //prints all the data to html
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        record[i].Name +
        "</td><td>" +
        record[i].City +
        "</td><td>" +
        record[i].Country +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("dis").innerHTML = out;
}
```

the following errors occur

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Practice/CMPE%20273%20refresher/json/Sample.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.transmit1 @ JSON.js:36transmit @ JSON.js:41onclick @ jsonweb.html:11

JSON.js:36 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Practice/CMPE%20273%20refresher/json/Sample.json'.

Comment: Don't serve from the filesystem.

Comment: If you want to read file simple.json from your file system then you need servlet URL not url as "simple.json".

Answer (score 1):

You are running the script with the `file://` protocol. you won't be able to perform that request with this protocol. you need to install a `http` server in order to be able to perform the request (even if it's everything in your computer).

there are many [lightweight](http://www.lighttpd.net) http servers to choose from or you can install nodejs or a xampp/wampp server.

Comment: can't it be done without installing server. Can I upload this ".json" file to dropbox and give the url. Would it work then? coz it will be at server then I guess

Comment: I actually do it without installing the server. How can i do it? read a local .json file. Its actually my course assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Hey your URL is not correct. Please ref this

> xmlhttp.open("GET", url,true);
>
> Specifies the type of request, the URL, and if the request should be handled asynchronously or not.

```
method: the type of request: GET or POST
url: the location of the file on the server
async: true (asynchronous) or false (synchronous)
```

Comment: Should mention that async is depricated and bad

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a compliant HTML5 browser you can use the FileReader API.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946430/2476389