# Why is my JS file not getting my json code?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to use json code in an HTML table, but the javascript file is not getting the json code. It's valid json and everything else in the javascript file is working correctly, but the $.getJSON is not called at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $.getJSON("objects.json", function(data) { 
        var stars = ''; 
        $.each(data, function (i, f) { 

            stars += '<tr>' + 
                '<td>' + f.name + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + f.orbiting + '</td>' + 
                '</tr>'; 
        }); 
        $('#table').append(stars); 
    }); 
});
```

Nothing after the function(data) happens at all.

This is the objects.json file, which is located in the same folder as the main.js file:

```
{
"stars": [
    {
      "name": "Sun",

      .......

      "siderealRotation": 609.12,
      "obliquityToOrbit": 7.25,
      "speedRelativeToStars": 19.4,
      "orbiting": "Galactic Center",

      ....
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: You are trying to loop over data which is an object that contains starts array, also, please mention more details if there's any console errors

Comment: Are you loading your page from `localhost`? [$.getJSON will only work if your objects.json is being served over http and not the local file protocol.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533078/getjson-not-working-with-local-json-file)

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. There are no console errors, and I changed it to loop over data.stars, but the problem still is that nothing in the function is called whatsoever. I even tried adding a hard-coded "$('#table').append("hhhhh");" and still not even that is called.

Comment: Would I be able to load it over GitHub or something?

Comment: I tried using json bin, still nothing working :(

Answer (score 0):

In you JSON is a  Object. `data.stars` is a array.

so use

```
$.each(data.stars, function (i, f) {
```

instead of

```
$.each(data, function (i, f) {
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding but it still shows nothing.

Comment: I even added an extra hard-coded line inside the function and even that is not called

Comment: can you make it `JSON.parse(data)` instead `data` in `$.each`