# Uploading jpeg in firebase storage from camera using ngCordova camera plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-storage

I'm struggling to upload images into firebase storage from ngCordova camera plugin in a Ionic app.

I can't use the fileTransfert plugin cause there is no database url with firebase storage (unless I'm wrong...) and I can only store file.

Do you have some ideas on how to perform that?

Here is my code at the moment using cordova file to read and converting in blob:

```
$scope.fromLibrairy = function() { 
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    targetWidth: 300, 
    targetHeight: 300, 
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageURI) {
    $scope.imgURI = imageURI;

    var name = imageURI.substring(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1, imageURI.length);
    var directory = imageURI.substring(0, imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    $cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(directory, name).then(function(success) { 
      alert(success);
      var blob = new Blob([success], { type:"image/jpeg" });

      // Create the storage ref
      var ref = storageRef.child('images/' + name); 
      // My function to upload in firebase storage (it works with jpeg)
      $scope.uploadPhoto(blob, ref);

    }, function (error) {
      alert("erreur du readAsArrayBuffer" + error + error.code);
    })

  }, function(error){
    alert('erreur du getPicture' + error);    
  });

});
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
var name = imageURI.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
var directory = cordova.file.tempDirectory;
```

Make sure you have the `$cordovaFile` plugin installed and ng-cordova configured properly.

please include the specific error log information

otherwise complete solution here is similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708624/122313